# Printing using CUPS via Internet

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, iot, cups

How do I print from across the Internet using CUPS? Installed Cups in Raspberry Pi, i can control printer through CUPS only on LAN network, is it possible to access printer through cups on global network via laptop/mobile from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the CUPS admin page (e.g.: `http://localhost:631/admin`) and enable the following options: "Share printers connected to this system" and "Allow printing from the Internet are checked".

Comment: Hey thanks ,  I followed the steps u mentioned and yes the printer on different network was detected.But I am now tring to give print it gives error message as :-Unable to locate printer "raspberrypi.local". Please help with this , I have tried a lot and gone with much stuff ,cant find solution.

Comment: This seems to be a network issue. Maybe the printer is not accessible from your raspberry... you have to check it. Also, you can edit your question providing more information. The more information you put, more chances you have to get help from the community. And if the answer solves your problem, you can mark it as "the answer".

Comment: The printer is accessible when controlled in same wifi network , it gives print successfully. But I want to access the printer from another network thru internet.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Besides enabling the "Internet printing" option, you also have network access to your printer, in order to correctly receive and treat requests from "Internet"... You have to check this...

Comment: I have given access through cupsd.conf file on print server by editing it at Location policy still cant get access to get print.

Comment: Is your print server accessible from where you are trying to remotely send the print command? Have you tried `ping` it? I still think it is some network communication issue...

Comment: No , I cant ping it as the print sever in LAN network  having local address. And I am trying to ping it from Printer Client which is on another Wifi network.What network configuartion should I do to make this possible?

Comment: I think you have to contact the network administrator... This configuration is out of this SOF purpose... I would recommend, if you really have to configure by yourself, ask your network question in "https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/" or "https://serverfault.com/"... I hope you get success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the port forward the of the raspberry pi IP address from the router through which the raspberry pi is connected for internet connection. After that you need to create the dynamic dns of the port forwarded and then you will get the access of the printer from remote connection